# How to add dynamic meta tag like categoryname: subcategoryname:productname in magento

Tags: magento, meta-tags

I would like to add meta tags in my product page like
 > , : my company name

currently I am using meta descriptions in my magento admin.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

you can go to View.phtml from Product module, and there you put something like that

```
<?php echo '<'.Mage::getStoreConfig('company_name').'>' ?> 
<?php echo '<'.Mage::getStoreConfig('other').'>' ?>
```

Comment: But Mage::getStoreConfig('company_name') will give me company name from the store config. What is need is to get the meta tag placed on every item like category name: subcategory name: company name.

Comment: on product view you can do that, $this->getProduct->getData('data_name';

Comment: Thanks every one for the answers. I find the best answer. Go to the admin of magento and in the manage product in meta data you can update that.